# Kentico: How to get children for selected parent page (in page selector) into uni selector?

Tags: kentico

I have a widget configuration with following setup in properties:
[image]
When user selects *Page* through page selector and now wants to select *Tiles*, I want to display all children of the *Page* in selection grid for Uni Selector. How can I achieve that?

I was trying to add some "where" condition but with no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

You usually can access another field via the macros 
{% Page.Value %} or if that doesn't work, then {% Fields["Page"].Value %}

Try those first, depending on what the Page returns (usually a page selector returns the GUID, so your where condition would have to be based on that).

Another note is that the object type CMS.document MAY not include the CMS_Tree data along with it.  It is not recommended you select documents anyway because of things like work flows, where as selecting a Tree Node is safer because there is only 1 "Node" where there can be many Documents (language variants).

If you switch your Tiles to be Node, then the where would be:

```
 NodeParentID = (Select top 1 NodeID from CMS_Tree where NodeGUID = '{% Page.Value %}')
```

If you need to keep it Document instead, then you would want

```
DocumentNodeID in (SELECT NodeID FROM CMS_Tree where NodeParentID = (Select top 1 NodeID from CMS_Tree where NodeGUID = '{% Page.Value %}'))
```

Lastly, if you are trying to create a many-to-many relationship, i'm finishing up right now a Many-To-Many selector tool so you can utilize Custom Binding Classes.  If you want it early, shoot me a message @ devtrev.com